# How to get list of eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse

I missed my workspace in which I was working.
Any one have idea about how to get list of all workspace of ecliplse.
when we start eclipse it show just 5-6 workspace only.

Comment: workspace or projects you see when you start eclipse?

Comment: One thing you can do is search your filesystem for the directory ".metadata".  This will catch even workspaces that aren't named "workspace".

Comment: @paulsm4 : it's not giving me anything related to workspace, any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this preference - 'Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces > Number of recent workspaces to remember'